# Referring to a different cell and extracting Substrings in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach, substring

I have 2 sheets, "Report" and "Data". In the "Data" sheet are values in column A as follows T-Shirt.Adidas.25.110 I need to take the raw data and input them into the "Report" Sheet as separate entities.

ex. Cell A1 will read "T-Shirt" Cell B1 will read "Adidas"

Here is what I have so far. Its a with statement but that will only work for one line. Im not sure how to loop it.

```
Dim Cell As Object
Dim Data As Range
Dim Report As Range
Set Report = Worksheets("Report").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set Data = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

With Report
    .Resize(1, 4) = Split(Worksheets("Data").Range("A2"), ".")
End With
```

The macro needs to work for any number of objects in the data sheet. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language/program is that? Excel? Please edit your question and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Yes this is for excel vba. sorry

Comment: Ok, but if you check the desciption of that tag (just put your mouse over it), it says: "If your question is specifically about programming Excel, Access, Word or Outlook, also use the appropriate tag: [tag:excel-vba], [tag:access-vba], [tag:word-vba] or [tag:outlook-vba]." So please edit it again to add excel-vba. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to loop:

```
Sub test()

Dim Cell As Object
Dim Data As Range
Dim Report As Range
Dim i As Long, TempArray As Variant

Set Data = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2", Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set Report = Worksheets("Report").Range("A2")

For i = 1 To Data.Count
    TempArray = Split(Data.Range("A" & i), ".")
    Report.Offset(i - 1).Resize(1, UBound(TempArray) + 1) = TempArray
Next i
Set TempArray = Nothing

End Sub
```

This way you use the Data as the source and count of iterations, and you can generalize the columns based on the number of periods in a given piece of data.